# C++ Undo Command / Reverse to previous state

Tags: c++, console, command, undo

I have a grid of randomly generated numbers of size `gameSize` (user input) which is contained within a vector of vectors. The user can enter two co-ordinates (x, y) so that it changes a number within the grid to a predefined value, which is "0".

So for example the user enters, X:0 Y:0 and:

```
{9, 7, 9}

{9, 6, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

becomes:

```
{0, 7, 9} <-- Changes position 0,0 to 0 (the predefined value)

{9, 6, 8} 

{5, 1, 4}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add an "undo" feature in which the user is prompted if they want to undo their selection or not, and if Yes then reverse the selection so that position 0,0 changes back to the original value (which is the value 9 in this example). How can I implement this? I understand I need to somehow record a previous grid state but have no clue how.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to be able to "undo" the last change, then you could simply make a copy, a backup of sorts, of the state *before* doing the change. Then if the user wants to "undo" the change then copy from the backup into the actual data.

For more levels of undo you could have a stack of copies.

---

If the data is large, then instead of copying the data for every change just store a copy of the actual change instead. Then when the user wants to "undo" you do the opposite of the change.

Example: If the user want to modify coordinates X,Y by Z, then store X, Y and Z. Then when doing undo you modify X,Y with -Z.

Comment: Actually, it suffices to store the previous value and x, y coordinates. Storing them in a struct, a vector of all such changes would allow to undo and even redo multiple user actions...

Comment: @chariked As long as you make sure the "undo" copy is up to date before the change it doesn't really matter how you do it. A full copy is safe, but might be ineffective if the vectors become large. Copy just the "cell" that's about to change could work very well.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented languages you often find that people will use the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to implement undo systems. Some people might say it's overkill but it is really quite flexible and doesn't take much boiler plate to get started.

The general idea is that you create an interface, with the methods `execute()` and `undo()`. You then you can create a whole slew of other classes that implement that interface and that know how do specific actions (e.g., in your example change position) and how to undo them. You then just need to keep track of commands that you have executed by putting them on a stack, and when you need to undo just pop them from the stack and call `undo()`.

[Here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) is a good resource for learning about the command pattern and design patterns in general.